# How to customize listview to have different layouts for first and second position of row items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view, baseadapter

I am working on a project where i need to customize the listview with different layouts for each row item as follows
(i)   First position  in a row item should be a normal **imageview** and **textview**
(ii)  Second position in a row item should be a **horizontal** **listview**
(iii) Third position  in a row itme should be a normal **custom** **listview**

I know all of these things to do separately but i dont know how to proceed to merge into a single listview by only changing the row items position. The image of my exact requirement is [image] . 
 Also i am sharing you some piece of code for custom listview adapter class for your reference

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;

    String[] country;
      int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] country, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.country = country;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return country.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtcountry;
        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtcountry.setText(country[position]);

        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

        return itemView;
    } <br>
```

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inflate each row with different view in the adapter. Use:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if(position==0)
{
//view 1
}

else if(position==1)
{
//View 2
}

else
{
Rest of the list elements
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. How to inflate layouts for each position?? can u please ellaborate??

Comment: @Chandru  View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false); Use different layouts for top 2 elements. For rest of elements, use the layout you want as listview element.

Comment: Then i should inflate layouts three time according to the positions right??

Comment: @Chandru Yes. First one is a layout with textview and edittext, second one is a horizontal listview, and rest are rows of the listview you want.

Comment: I got your point then what change should i need to make in getCount(), getItem(), getItemId() override methods???

Comment: @Chandru Make the count equal to the no of rows in listview +2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55670/discussion-between-chandru-and-berserk).

Comment: see this [you can relate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336847/nullpointer-exception-in-listview-creating-separate-layout-for-listitems)