# NullPointer Exception in listview,creating separate layout for listitems?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

I created a listview that contains two types of items either text or image.But i am getting nullpointer exception only on when i scrolling down. 
my adapter's code is this.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ListModel> myList = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 2;


public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListModel> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

}


int type;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ListModel listModel = myList.get(position);
    String data = listModel.getType();
  /*  if (data.equals("Text")) {
        return type1;
    } else if (data.equals("Image")) {
        return type2;

    }return 0;*/

    if (data.equals("Text")) {
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;
    } else if (data.equals("Image")) {
        type = TYPE_ITEM2;
    }
    return type;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return myList.size() + 1;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}


@Override
public ListModel getItem(int position) {
    // return myList.get(position);

    if (position >= myList.size()) {
        return null;
    }
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    View v = convertView;
    TextView textView = null;
    ImageView imageView = null;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + v + " type = " + type);
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM1) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_text, null);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        } else if (type == TYPE_ITEM2) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image, null);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        }
        holder.textView = textView;
        holder.imageView = imageView;
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    ListModel model = myList.get(position);
    String datatype = model.getType();

    if (datatype.equals("Text")) {

        holder.textView.setText(model.getData());

    } else if (datatype.equals("Image")) {

        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.imageView, model.getData());


    }

    return v;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;


}}
```

The error is 
`java.lang.NullPointerException` in line 117, it is the textView,

Comment: Please add the tag corresponding to the programming language used in your code snippet.

Comment: Please see i have added already. @Kryptos

Comment: You did not, since the language is "Java". Android is a platform not a language. I did it for you, anyway.

Comment: `getItemViewType` returns zero-based index. That is 0 or 1, not 1 or 2.

Comment: you just changed the whole question, making previous comment and answers obsolete. This is not the way to go. Stackoverflow is not a debugging solution. When you have other questions, create another post or at least keep the previous one and just add some text below it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a classic `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Don't forget that arrays in java (like in most programming language) are 0-indexed, meanign the first element is at index `0` (not `1`).

You haven't shown any caller code, but most likely some of your code are calling methods `getItem()` or `getView()` with a position which value is `2` where it should be `1` (to access to second element in the list).

If you cannot control the caller (maybe it is from an third-party library), then I suggest that:

- offset the value of `position` by -1. But this might break some other part of your code.
- add some protection in your code to prevent exception, such as:

> ```
> public ListModel getItem(int position) {
>     if (position >= myList.size()) {
>         // TODO: log an error, show a message, etc.
>         return null; // or a default value
>     }
>     return myList.get(position);
> }
> ```

It is also possible that the values you chose for `TYPE_ITEM1` and `TYPE_ITEM2` are not well if they must represent indices in arrays. Consider using `0` and `1` instead.

Comment: I resolved the `OutOfBoundException` but now i am getting `NPE` in `holder.textView.setText(model.getData());` only when i scrolling.

Comment: @devendra about what specifically ?

Comment: @Kryptos like **You haven't shown any caller code, but most likely some of your code are calling methods getItem() or getView() with a position which value is 2 where it should be 1 (to access to second element in the list).** what does that implies?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your `getItemViewType`. You should return a zero-based index (i.e. 0 or 1 not 1 or 0). From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)):

> Note: Integers must be in the range 0 to getViewTypeCount() - 1